# How to upload packages to an instance in a Processing step in Sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, package, amazon-sagemaker

I have to do large scale feature engineering on some data. My current approach is to spin up an instance using `SKLearnProcessor` and then scale the job by choosing a larger instance size or increasing the number of instances. I require using some packages that are not installed on Sagemaker instances by default and so I want to install the packages using .whl files.

Another hurdle is that the Sagemaker role does not have internet access.

```
import boto3
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

sess = sagemaker.Session()
sess.default_bucket()        

region = boto3.session.Session().region_name

role = get_execution_role()
sklearn_processor = SKLearnProcessor(framework_version='0.20.0',
                                     role=role,
                                     sagemaker_session = sess,
                                     instance_type="ml.t3.medium",
                                     instance_count=1)

sklearn_processor.run(code='script.py')
```

**Attempted resolutions:**

1. Upload the packages to a CodeCommit repository and clone the repo into the SKLearnProcessor instances. Failed with error `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com': No such device or address`. I tried cloning the repo into a sagemaker notebook instance and it works, so its not a problem with my script.
2. Use a bash script to copy the packages from s3 using the CLI. The bash script I used is based off [this post](https://medium.com/@shadidc/installing-custom-python-package-to-sagemaker-notebook-b7b897f4f655). But the packages never get copied, and an error message is not thrown.
3. Also looked into using the package `s3fs` but it didn't seem suitable to copy the wheel files.

**Alternatives**

My client is hesitant to spin up containers from custom docker images. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2. Use a bash script to copy the packages from s3 using the CLI. The bash script I used is based off this post. But the packages never get copied, and an error message is not thrown.`

This approach seems sound.

You may be better off overriding the `command` field on the `SKLearnProcessor` to `/bin/bash`, run a bash script like `install_and_run_my_python_code.sh` that installs the wheel containing your python dependencies, then runs your main python entry point script.

Additionally, instead of using AWS S3 calls to download your code in a script, you could use a [ProcessingInput](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html#sagemaker.processing.ProcessingInput) to download your code rather than doing this with AWS CLI calls in a bash script, which is what the `SKLearnProcessor` does to download your entry point `script.py` code across all the instances.

Comment: Thanks, `ProcessingInput` seems like the most elegant way to go!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple other options. Here's all the options I could think of (some have been mentioned)

1. Use `sagemaker.processing.*Processor.run(code=<bash script>)` bash script to pull from repo: Commit to Codecommit/Github/Bitbucket repo and use your run bash script to setup by cloning from that same repo
2. Hijack `ProcessingInput`: point `ProcessingInput` to a local directory, or do pre-setup by uploading files to S3 and point `ProcessingInput` to that same S3.
3. Make your library into a package and push to a local repo (Nexus, EC2, CodArtifact, support this) and install these like any python package with bash run file.
4. Hijack `sagemaker.sklearn.estimator` and use `source_dir` to specify your entire source directory
5. Compile a wheel from your package and push to container with `ProcessingInput` and install.

None of these are great.  I didn't do 1, because I didn't want to push latest code each time to test,  didn't want to build a package (3) or compile a wheel (5), and Using an estimator to run a processing job seems wrong. Went with 2 and in my case it's necessary to get individual files in the right place (`ProcessingInput` doesn't support individual files, and I had pyproject.toml in a higher directory) so my job script that runs the job does pre-setup by ordering and uploading files to S3, and I specify an S3 uri in `ProcessingInput`.